# How can I check a batch of epubs with epubcheck on my Mac?

Tags: command-line-interface, epub

I want to run epubcheck on a directory of epub files and log the results of the epubcheck validity checks. Is there any existing CLI script that I can use for this that wraps epubcheck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, posting it here for anyone having the same issue.

The quick solution to be 100% CLI.

```
for z in path/*.epub; do epubcheck $z; done &> log.txt
```

Found it here: https://mralphaville.wordpress.com/2013/09/28/epubcheck-on-linux/